# Loading message gif does not work when keyboard is pressed. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

We are using [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net)and [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)to check username availability using `text_changed` event.

Here is the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)with [html](/questions/tagged/html)markup:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptmanager1" runat="server">
  </asp:ScriptManager>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);

    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
      var state = document.getElementById('loadingdiv').style.display;
      if (state == 'block') {
        document.getElementById('loadingdiv').style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('loadingdiv').style.display = 'block';
      }
      args.get_postBackElement().disabled = true;
    }
  </script>
  <div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="PnlUsrDetails" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              UserName:
            </td>
            <td>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ontextchanged="txtUsername_TextChanged" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <div id="checkusername" runat="server" Visible="false">
                <asp:Image ID="imgstatus" runat="server" Width="17px" Height="17px" />
                <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="waitingdiv" id="loadingdiv" style="display:none; margin-removed5.3em">
          <img src="LoadingImage.gif" alt="Loading" />Please wait...
        </div>
      </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </div>
</form>
```

When you copy and paste a username, the waiting message gif is activated and it works.

However, if you type the username on your keyboard, nothing happens, not even a message indicating username is available or username is taken.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: `margin-removed5.3em` invalid CSS property.

Comment: You should use the `onKeyUp` client event. But it must be invoked from JavaScript to make the request to the server through **`XMLHttpRequest`**, sending the data to a particular method.